# Instruments Leaks / Weird Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm testing my app on Instruments -> Leaks

And I have a leak that I can't eliminate, because I can't understand its roots.

What should I do?

P.S. These leaks appear after such steps:

1. App goes to background with visible keyboard.
2. App goes to foreground.
3. I enter any letter on the keyboard.

If the keyboard is invisible before going to background = no leaks
[one http://iwheelbuy.com/leak.png](http://iwheelbuy.com/leak.png)
[two http://iwheelbuy.com/leak1.png](http://iwheelbuy.com/leak1.png)
[three http://iwheelbuy.com/leak2.png](http://iwheelbuy.com/leak2.png)

Comment: Are you using xcode 4.5 by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest in applicationWillEnterBackground in AppDelegate.h, just resign First responder.